# Can processes with long range dependence be classified as stationary/non-stationary?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity, long-range-dependence

If my process has long range dependence (hurst exponent > 0.5 ) can it be concluded that it is stationary/non-stationary? How?
Is there any correlation between Long range dependence and Stationarity?

Comment: One way would be to use a Fourier series approach and apply a regular test for stationarity.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Please read the updated question once.

Comment: Wide-sense stationary is assessed by a linear model so it has nothing to do with the length of the series anymore than a simple linear fit has to do with the number of rows in its training set.